# Crash when initializing realm object

Tags: ios, realm, nsnumber

I try initialize subclass of Realm Object, but in `[super init]` on field `if (self && (_objectSchema = [self.class sharedSchema]))` the app is crashes with follow message:

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason:
>   ''NSNumber' is not supported as an RLMObject property. Supported
>   number types include int, long, float, double, and other primitive
>   number types"

If anybody has any idea on how to debug this problem, please let me know.

Comment: Take a look at the interface of your RLMObject subclass and replace any properties typed `NSNumber*` with a primitive type appropriate for the property.

Comment: I have two properties with double and NSString types. I note that the same crash occurs when I call [RLMRealm defaultRealm]. So the problem is not with initialization

Comment: Can you please post your initialization method source code here for us to see? That error definitely makes it sound like something isn't being properly configured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exception speaks for itself. You have `NSNumber` property on a `RLMObject` subclass and it is not listed in excluded properties. Probably you have it in a superclass of your object or in class extension.

If you don't have that property on the class, it may be so that you have this property on some superclass/subclass. Maybe on the other `RLMObject` subclass. As you've noticed in the comments, crash also occurs when you `[RLMRealm defaultRealm]`, this really points to the issue I describe. Two caveats:

1. Even if you don't instantiate your subclass it is used to generate schema,
2. Check **ALL** your `RLMObject` subclasses if they have any `NSNumber` property.

Comment: _objectSchema is not NSNumber. 
to be precise, crash occurs in method
+ (instancetype)sharedSchema.

Comment: Added some hints to the answer.

Comment: You are right. Once I have created RLMObject subclasses, but not instantiated them. They just hung, but were needed for generating schema. Thanks!